# Batch is taking 7-15 minutes to processing 50k records

Tags: batch-processing, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I am trying to fetch 50k records using SAP Query connector and send it to S3. but it is taking 7 minutes to process 50 k records in batch.It is taking time at the time at loading phase for instance. I have put S3 to aggregator. Still facing issue and also for next 50k records batch is taking 15 to 16 minutes and next records 30minutes. Can anyone help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9oDx.png)

Comment: Can you add your batch config. Also try to use xml code snippet instead of images.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. The screenshot is nearly useless for troubleshooting.

How do you know the time is spent in the loading phase? How much time takes to read the same SAP records without batch? Exact versions of every component including Mule runtime? Is it executing locally in your computer, in a server, CloudHub or RTF? Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.